# share folder become slow when multi users are using it

Tags: smb, sharing

I have a file server with many shared folders ,
Is there a way to limit speed per connection?
when more then 2-3 users uploading and
downloading files from server then
there is overload and sometimes its stuck
i've tried to see if there are any things to do but no luck
thanks

Comment: Buy faster disks?

Comment: Enable QoS in the router (if supported).

Comment: @DavidPostill i got ssd , the port is 1000mbit

Comment: @harrymc they connected to switch unmannged

Comment: @mikuzan what operating system is the file server using, windows?

Comment: The port may be fast, but the question is the capacity of your router and the connecting speed to the ISP, for effective speed. To test it, use for example https://www.speedtest.net/

Comment: @Cpt.Whale windows server 2019

Answer (score 0):

There you can set quite a few settings with [Set-SmbServerConfiguration](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/smbshare/get-smbserverconfiguration?view=windowsserver2019-ps):

```
Set-SmbServerConfiguration -MaxChannelPerSession 16

# some of the more performance-based settings and their defaults:
MaxChannelPerSession    : 32 
MaxMpxCount             : 50 
MaxSessionPerConnection : 16384 
MaxThreadsPerQueue      : 20 
MaxWorkItems            : 1
```

You can view all the current settings with `Get-SmbServerConfiguration`

The performance impact of each really depends on your file server's performance, and how each client decides to connect